# python concurrent.futures getting result slows down

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

when I try getting the result, it feels like it goes back too not being threaded, but when I don't grab the result. it works like it has 10 threads, any idea why or how I can fix this?

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
    info = pool.submit(check, "Username").result().result
    print(info)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Future.result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) blocks until the result is available.  If you want several tasks to run concurrently, you need to submit them all before waiting for the results.

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

# Submit tasks
future1 = pool.submit(...)
future2 = pool.submit(...)

# Get task results
result1 = future1.result()
result2 = future2.result()
```